# What should I do if I realize that my question is a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, post-ban

I had a question in which there was a problem solving another problem. It already has three downvotes. Now I have found an easier and simpler solution to the base problem from another Stack Overflow question. I thought about just deleting it, but I'm banned from asking right now. I don't think that question can be improved. What should I do to that question so that it does not resist me from being free from my question ban?

Comment: Flag it as a duplicate if you can.

Comment: @Paulie_D I can do that, I can even raise close vote on my question, but would that help me to get out of my ban?

Comment: No, it won't. It won't hurt either. The only thing that can help you out of the ban is improving existing questions so they receive upvotes, or post good questions in the future so they are well received.

Comment: @yivi "post good questions in the future so they are well received", how can I do that? I get out of the ban after an upvote, and before I ask a new good question, someone downvotes one of my questions, banning me again from asking. Is there any way to get out of this cycle?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: @gnat No, it doesn't. I have read all (upvoted) answers to that question months before, but any of those doesn't answer this. I can't delete or close vote or flag as I'm question banned right now, and these actions will make the situation even worse.

Comment: BTW, deleted questions are included in the question ban algorithm. So deleting it wouldn't improve things. OTOH, people can't downvote deleted questions (but they can't upvote them either), so I guess deleting may be useful on a question that continues to gather downvotes.

Comment: Banning is to protect against bots, mostly. Just forget about SO for a few weeks and then carry on as usual.

Comment: @dagelf Do you mean 6 months by "a few weeks"? That will rarely occur as I'm being banned and unbanned because of continuous upvotes and downvotes, resetting the timer.